# how to check if a table exists in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

First, let me tell you I checked a bunch of the "How to check if a table exists in ...". I nevertheless need some more information about the query

```sql
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';
```

I supposed I had to change the names "sqlite_master" and "table_name", and here is my code

```cs
// a static function of the public class "SqliteBase"
public static void CreerBase(string dataSource)
{
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();

    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + dataSource;
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);

    // Create table if it does not exist
    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS beispiel ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);";
    Console.WriteLine("La Table a bien été créée");
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

and the unit test function :

```
[TestMethod]  
public void LaCreationBaseMarche()
{
    string dataSource = "beispiel.db";
    SqliteBase.CreerBase(dataSource);
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();

    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + dataSource;
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
    command.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'beispiel';";
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    Assert.Equals("beispiel", reader[0].ToString());
    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();

    command.Dispose();

}
```

My problem is : the `command.executeReader()` of the test method returns me a "null" reader, and of course i got an error when I try to do reader[0].. Did I misused the query ?

**EDIT :** Ok, I though I had to use the name of the file ^^. Now I changed it, but it still doesn't work (same error). I also changed the name "exemple.db" in "beispiel.db". I updated my code :)

Thank you in advance for your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see it, you don't read from the reader:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LaCreationBaseMarche()
{
    string dataSource = "exemple.db";
    SqliteBase.CreerBase(dataSource);
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();

    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + dataSource;
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
    command.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM exemple WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'beispiel';";
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Assert.Equals("beispiel", reader[0].ToString());
    }

    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();
    command.Dispose();
}
```

**EDIT**

A possible problem is the dataSource. You have to make sure, that both methods access the same location.

Comment: That's a point, but the main problem is that my reader actually hasn't rows ^^ ! And I don't understand why my previous query doesn't work x)

Comment: The method `CreerBase` works and the table is created?

Comment: Ok, good question.. Actually, it was what i was trying to test.. How can you figure that out ? Where should it be if it exists ? (I'm working on Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: Simplest solution I can think of right now: change your querry to "SELECT name FROM exemple WHERE type = 'table'" and debug the loop. Take a look at all results

Comment: Ok the reader's value is still "null". But then, what is wrong in my first code part ?

Comment: If you changed your querry as I suggested, I think there is a problem with your database connection. It should return you at least something

Comment: What I meant was " SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150270/discussion-between-doe-jowns-and-romano-zumbe).

Comment: The problem was indeed in the datasource name and not in the query ! Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 5):

No, you didn't have to change the `sqlite_master`. That's SQLite's metadata table which contains information about all objects known to SQLite.

So your query will become:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='beispiel';
```

Comment: Ok, I though I had to use the name of the file ^^. Now I changed it, but it still doesn't work (same error).

Answer (score 5):

I did the following to check if a table already exists in the database

```
public static bool tableAlreadyExists(SqliteConnection openConnection, string tableName)
{
  var sql = 
  "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='"+tableName +"';"; 
  if(openConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {   
        SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sql, openConnection);
        SqliteDataReader reader =command.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Close(); // @al000y: thanks mate
            return true;
        }
        reader.Close(); // @al000y: thanks mate
        return false;
    }else{
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Data.ConnectionState must be open");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite neat useful for testing as well when you use an in-memory version of the Sqlite database

Comment: Very useful method, I would sugest though, to write it as an extension method:
`public static bool ExistsTable(this SQLiteConnection con, string tableName) { ... }`

Comment: A very nice solution

Comment: Add reader.Close(); before the return statement or you will get Database locked error if you are trying to update/delete records

Comment: @al000y Thanks for pointing this out. Code sample updated. Any pointers if something else should be improved are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to query `sqlite_master` table:

`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'beispiel';`